# How to start Thread with lambda expression c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have this class:

```
public class Statistics
{
    List<string> _lsit;

    public List<string> ipList
    {
        get { return _lsit; }
        set { _lsit = value; }
    }

    string _Path = @"C:\Program Files\myApp.exe";
    string _Path = "";
    ProcessStartInfo ps = null;

    public getStatistics(string Path)
    {
        _Path = Path;
        getStatistics();
    }
}
```

I want to start the function Statistics with different Thead and i did somthing like:

```
Statistics stat = new Statistics (some path);
Thread<List<string>> lList = new Thread<List<string>>(() => tsharkIps.getStatistics());
```

but the compiler Error says "The non-generic type 'System.Threading.Thread' cannot be used with type arguments"

I did not write all my class and only want to know hot to start the thread

thanks

Comment: I think you are looking for Task<T> instead of Thread ... and there you should use Task.Factory to start the Task ;)

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and pay more attention to your sample code (and to clarity) for your next question.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to take a step back to start with and *read the compiler error*. `Thread` is not a generic type. It's really not at *all* clear what you're trying to do here, especially as you haven't even *shown* a parameterless `getStatistics()` method (which should be called `GetStatistics()` to follow .NET naming conventions) and the parameterized `getStatistics()` method you *have* shown doesn't have a return type.

Starting a thread with a lambda expression is the easy part:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => CallSomeMethodHere());
thread.Start();
```

It's not clear how that translates to your sample code though.

Or using the TPL in .NET 4, you can (and probably *should* use `Task` or `Task<T>`):

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CallSomeMethodHere());
```

or

```
Task<string> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CallSomeMethodReturningString());
```

It's possible that you *really* want:

```
Task<List<string>> statisticsTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
   Statistics statistics = new Statistics(path);
   return statistics.ipList();
});
```

Note that here the *constructor* is called within the new task - which is important, as it looks like that's probably doing all the work. (That's usually a bad idea to start with, but that's another matter.)

You should look at [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) in general, btw...

Comment: thank you i will try this but i cannot use Task because i am using .Net 3.5, and my method getStatistics() it is only example